# Link from external to specific part on a one page site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built my site based on a bootstrap template. It's a one page site with scrolling but I am currently redeveloping it so that my portfolio pages are separate pages and link back to the homepage. I want to link back to the gallery on the one page part of the site and therefore need to link to the homepage and get it to scroll instantly to the gallery. Any ideas on how I would do this. Site as it was is at www.js-gd.co.uk

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 0):

You could add an id to the section you are wanting and then have `url.com/page#id`
If you post the code I will be sure to help you

Comment: tried that and it didn't work. Which part of the code do you need as its rather a big site. The actually link is an icon <p class="text-center"><a class="chevron" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a></p>

Comment: Where on the home page are you trying to have it automatically go to. For example I did it on my site because I wanted it to go automatically to the contact page so I have <a href="http://goldtechsolutions.net/index.php#contact"> and it scrolls there. You can look

Comment: ah I tried just index.html/#work. I'm working locally at the moment  - maybe it needs to have the domain too

Comment: worked it out. Don't need the the forward slash. Thanks.

Comment: No Problem glad it worked. Would love if you check mark/mark it up my answer so people know its complete.